# Apply border to divs on every page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
    @page {
            size:A4 portrait; 
    }
    </style> 
    <style type="text/arial" media="print">    
            @page {
                margin: 75px 16px 75px 16px;
                @PageBreak{
                   page-break:always;
                    page-break-inside:avoid;
                } 
            }             
            div.headerqwe{
            postion:running(headerqwe); 
            width:750px;
            height:960px;
             border-top:1.2px solid black;
           border-bottom:1.2px solid black;
              border-left:1.2px solid black;
           border-right:1.2px solid black;
            }
        </style>                           
    </head>
           <div class="headerqwe">
            <table border="2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
                <tr>           
                    <td align="center">
                        <apex:outputText value="Page " style="font-face:verdana;font-size:0.68em;"/>
     <span class="pagenumber" style="font-face:verdana;font-size:0.68em;"/> 
                    <apex:outputText value="of" style="font-face:verdana;font-size:0.68em;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px"/> 
                    <span class="pagecount" style="font-face:verdana;font-size:0.68em;"/>
                </td>
            </tr>         
        </table>
        </div>
```

I need to repeat `<div>` border on every page. Currently I'm getting the border only on the first page, and I need to get the border running on every page.

How can I do that?

Comment: give a class to the elements you want to target and apply border value to that class thru your CSS

Comment: CSS should go in a separate file, then that file must be referenced on every page where you want the same CSS styles.

Comment: in this css should not in different page

Comment: include style in every page or follow colemc comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) if you want to get to for all the div's your using assign style to div tag

```
  div{
   border:1.2px solid black
 }
```

2) if you apply styles for specified Div's append one class for that specified div's ..like BorderedDiv

```
div.BorderedDiv{
   border:1.2px solid black
 }
```

Comment: consider <div class="bordereddiv"></div> i will get the border .I want to get this on every page i am having .repeat this div page borderon every page

Comment: try to place the bordereddiv styles at common css file of your project , then you can use that class anywhere of your views which consist that css file